# Animation in THREE.js via collada

Tags: three.js, collada

I have been trying to export a skeletal animation, from Maya 2013 to THREE.js for quite some time, and I haven't seen this exact issue come up yet...

After getting frustrated for it not working. I resorted to copy and pasting the monster example then placing it with my model, my model has lost its animations. :( I baked them and everything when I exported in FBX-DAE.

I do get a warning but i don't know if it matters:
could not find transform "visibility" in node joint1.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the OpenCOLLADA exporter?

There's a new project under way that might be of interest to you. Export path would be Maya > OpenCOLLADA > gltF > Three.js

Here's the glTF loader for Three.js:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/loaders/threejs

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to have it in a Collada format? How about if you could export an animation from Maya directly to .JS?

You might be aware that THREE.js comes with an exporter for Maya, but it only works for static models. I have created an updated version that also supports exporting rigged and animated models. It doesn't require any intermediate steps: it just outputs straight to a .JS file. We have a pull request to integrate the updated exporter with the THREE trunk, but if you want to get the new and improved exporter immediately you can get it from this repository: https://github.com/BlackTowerEntertainment/three.js/tree/maya_animation_exporter. The exporter files are in utils/exporters/maya.

Hope this helps.